# Server error 500 instead of appending slash django when debug=false

Tags: python, django, nginx, django-urls, server-error

On production server I get 500 Server error when I access /visitors url. I use django 1.8 with nginx.

I think django should append slash at the end and then show me the actual page. If I access /visitors/ everything works fine.

When debug is set to True everything works fine.

I don't have any error in error.log and my access log is:
[image]
(sorry for picture, for some reason I am not able to copy/paste on server).

I am not a serveradmin so I don't know what files are relevant in errors like this one so let me know what you need and I paste it here.

**EDIT:**

settings.py

```
# ... other settings were deleted

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'ea.logs_middleware.LogsMiddleware',
    'ea.custom_login_middleware.FirstLoginMiddleware',
    'ea.profiler_middleware.ProfileMiddleware',
)


WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ea.wsgi.application'
```

I don't modified APPEND_SLASH and event if I add APPEND_SLASH=True it doesn't work.

**EDIT2**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^visitors/$', views.how_it_works, name='visitors'),

    # ...
]
```

Comment: Could you show your settings? In particular, the middlewares. Thanks.

Comment: Have you modified [APPEND_SLASH](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#append-slash)?

Comment: I modified my question.

Comment: Post your `urls.py` for `/visitors` as well as the urlconf that includes that `urls.py`. There's a slight chance it's your middleware order, specifically that `SecurityMiddleware` should be above `CommonMiddleware` but I think it's more likely in your `urls.py`. Also make sure that [this bug people find when upgrading to Django 1.9](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25878) isn't your issue.

Comment: /visitors are in the main urls.py file under project so there is only one file.

When I change the middleware order so Security is above Common, I get 502 Bad Gateway.

Comment: try this `url(r'^visitors\/*$', views.how_it_works, name='visitors')`